# How to use global object window or document in javascript es6 Class

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6, gulp, addeventlistener

How can I use the window or document inside a JavaScript ES6 class

I tried the following code

**Scenario #1:**

```
class App {

    constructor() {
        console.info('App Initialized');

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
           console.info('document Initialized');
           this.initializeView();
        }).bind(this);
    }

    initializeView() {
        console.info('View Initialized');
    }
}

const app = new App();
```

Note: I compiled the above code using *gulp js*

If I tried to call the class method inside the `document.addEventListener`, it throws the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.initializeView is not a function
```

So, I binded the `this` object to document `.bind(this)`

**Scenario #2:**

```
class App {

    constructor() {
        console.info('App Initialized');

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
           console.info('document Initialized');
        }).bind(this);
    }
}

const app = new App();
```

If I tried without `document.addEventListener`, its working as expected in browser but if I tried with the `document.addEventListener` it throws an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.addEventListener(...) is undefined
```

[image]

Please assist me how to use the window or document inside the es6 class.

**Scenarion #3:**

```
class Booking {

    stepper = 1;

    constructor() {
        console.info('Booking Initialized');

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            console.log('document Initialized')
        });
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following exception

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined
```

> The referred solution is not has any relevance to the Question's
> subject matter
> [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)
>
> I'm not sure how the expertise people giving the above link as a
> solution.

Comment: `document.addEventListener(...).bind(this)` makes no sense. Remove the `.bind(this)`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - I elaborated the question and also mentioned that why I used the `.bind(this)` please assist me how to run the code without any exception.

Comment: Then this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Here my question is how to use the `document` or `window` inside a class. I don't have confusion on the usage of `this` keyword.

Comment: It looks like you do, because you're using `.bind` incorrectly, in an attempt to access the `this` inside. tl;dr use an arrow function instead and remove the `.bind`

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Here the question's subject matter is **how to use the global object `window` or `document` inside the es6 class**. If I have mistakes in the code please correct and try to give solution for the subject matter. Now the discussion turned into a wrong dirction.

Comment: You really don't have to do anything at all in order to use them. `someMethod() { window.addEventListener('click', someFn)` will work just fine, for example. They can be used inside just like they can be used outside.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Please if you have any concern on the usage of .bind, mentioned it in the answer section as a Note. Also, I attached the browser console error for your reference. Please try the above code before giving strong suggestions. Please.

Comment: The error is caused by your incorrect use of `.bind(this)` on the call of `addEventListener`. Remove it, and use an arrow function instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance - I added one more scenario #3 as per your opinion in the question. Please check.

Comment: You have never defined an identifier named `options`, so yeah, it'll throw `Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined`... it's pretty self-explanatory...

Comment: @CertainPerformance - as a expertise you know, but I don't know. Could you please assist me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use a `function(){}` for your event handling, because regular functions derive `this` from the context at runtime, and that context is not your object, but the global context. Using the ancient `bind()` function (if done right) gets around that, but so does modern arrow function syntax, so use that instead.

```js
   constructor() {
        console.info('App Initialized');

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
           console.info('document Initialized');
           this.initializeView();
        });
    }
```

Done.

However, this is silly code and we don't have to do this at all: load your script in the `<head>` element, as `<script src="..." async defer></script>`, using [the `defer` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) so that your script doesn't run until the DOM is ready for queries. It's been around for about a decade now, no need for that event listening; just run the code that needs to run.

```js
   constructor() {
        console.info('App Initialized');
        this.initializeView();
    }
```